# Explicitly Specifying types for Express' "application, request, response..."

Tags: express, typescript

I'm working to update a simple NodeJS + ExpressJS app to use TypeScript. I've got it working, but I'm having fits adding some extra data annotations to add extra type checking and code-time autocomplete/IntelliSense in Visual Studio & WebStorm.

I've got the latest [express.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts) referenced. I've also created the Express app:

```
var app = express();
```

Everything works... but I can't seem to figure out how to add the type info for **app** for autocomplete assistance when you type something like

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){});
```

I've tried annotating **app** (and **req** & **res**) using `Express.Application` (and `.Request` & `.Response`) but that isn't resolving. Looking at the type definition I'm getting confused with how the typedef is written creating the internal "e" reference...

Surprised I can't find anyone asking & resolving this since the express.d.ts typedef was updated for ExpressJS 4.0 (previously I found references to **ExpressServer** but that isn't present today.

Ideas?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

*Classic case of "work on something for a while with no success, but when you finally post a question asking for help, you figure it out immediately".*

The solution:
When you want to use one of the types, you have to import the module as the typedef is in a named module within the typedef.

In the above code (that resided in my **app.ts**), I was getting the type annotations on **app**. Because my import statement at the top of the file was `import express = require('express');`, I could annotate the **req** & **res** params like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req:express.Request, res:express.Response){});
```

In other files, where I was trying to get type annotations on the **app**, I was missing the import statement at the top of the file. Once added, I could add the annotations for that as well like:

```
public init(app: express.Application){}
```

Comment: thanks, I was using `Express.Application` which exists, but has different types!

Comment: Another great thing is that you can enforce response body type by setting:
```js
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response<SomeDto>) => {})
```

Comment: `Express.Request` & `Express.Response` worked for me!

Comment: With TypeScript 3.8, types can also be imported explicitly using `import type` as mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types)

Answer (score 55):

I think some of these answers may be dated. The following worked for me:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Comment: what type to import for next in `app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response, next: ?) {
    throw new Error('NoRoutesMatched');
  });`

Comment: @ShubhamShaw I also imported NextFunction, like this `import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';` then used it like this `function myReqHandler (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { ... }`

Comment: You could use: `import type { Request, Response } from 'express';` (hint: `type` keyword)

Comment: If you want to import the Request & the Response with this syntax, you have to import '@types/express' library in the require dev.

`npm i -D @types/express`

Answer (score 44):

In case anyone stumbles on this question in 2017 and using a more modern TS. You should be able to just `npm install @types/express` and then it should just work.

Comment: Anyone else stumbling upon this, make sure you're doing `app = express()`, not `app = new express()`

Comment: Also in the scenario you're porting over a js file to ts, remember to change all the requires to imports for the error to go away in VS Code.